# How to trigger a clicked event on a Facebook 'like' button?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to run the following code, taken from the Facebook developer site. The alert that I put in 'You liked...' does not come up. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Div1">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <div id="fb-root">
                </div>
                <fb:like href="www.goal.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true">
                </fb:like>
                <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
                <script>
                    FB.init({
                        status: true, // Check login status.
                        cookie: true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
                        xfbml: true  // Parse XFBML.
                    });
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                    function (response) {
                        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add the <fb:like> AFTER you call the connect JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it. It **does** work.
http://jsfiddle.net/vyELp/ 
When I clicked the like button the alert just showed up.

Just a little hint: You should put `<script>` tags in the `<head>` section of your page.

Comment: Facebook is weird, the script-tags are placed correctly according to the documentation.

Comment: @RobinJ the login comes up, but the alert does not?